# Thrust::transform custom function

Tags: cuda, thrust

I am trying to do a very basic example within CUDA. I would like to do a simple calculation on a list of floats.

> vh[x] * k1 + k2

Currently I am trying this and it is not working:

**Code 1**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace thrust;

float k1 = 42, k2 = 7;

int main(void)
{
    vector<float> vh = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    device_vector<float> v = vh;
    device_vector<float> v_out(v.size());

    thrust::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v_out.begin(), [=] __device__(float x) {
        return x*k1 + k2;
    });

    for (size_t i = 0; i < v_out.size(); i++)
        std::cout << v_out[i] << std::endl;
}
```

I am getting a very annoying lambda function error with the above code so I have tried to use a custom function as the code below shows:

**Code 2**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace thrust;

float k1 = 42, k2 = 7;

float multiply(float x)
{
    return x * k1 + k2;
}

int main(void) {
    vector<float> vh = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    device_vector<float> v = vh;
    device_vector<float> v_out(v.size());
    thrust::negate<float> op;

    thrust::transform(v.begin(), v.end(), v_out.begin(), multiply __device__(float x) );

    for (size_t i = 0; i < v_out.size(); i++)
        std::cout << v_out[i] << std::endl;

    std::getwchar();
}
```

Can anyone tell my why Code 1 and/or Code 2 is not working?

Comment: What CUDA and thrust version are you using?

Comment: CUDA 7.5 and I guess it is Thrust 1.7.0. I havent updated it since I installed CUDA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Code 2, you must wrap your function in an object to create a functor.

For Code 1, you have to use `--expt-extended-lambda` nvcc option to enable full lambda support.

You also must declare `k1`, `k2` as `const`, or not make them static by (for instance) declaring it inside the `main`.

Use functor for production code, unless your lambda is **very** simple.

Check out the following code for a working example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace thrust;



template<class T>
struct saxpi{
    T k1;
    T k2;
    saxpi(T _k1, T _k2){
        k1=_k1;
        k2=_k2;
    }
    __host__ __device__ T operator()(T &x) const{
        return x*k1+k2;
    }
};


int main(void)
{
    float kk1=1, kk2=5;
    vector<float> vh = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    device_vector<float> v = vh;
    device_vector<float> v_out(v.size());
    cout<<"Lambda:"<<endl;
    auto ff = [=]  __device__ (float x) {return kk1*x +kk2;};

    thrust::transform(v.begin(),v.end(),v_out.begin(),ff);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < v_out.size(); i++)
        std::cout << v_out[i] << std::endl;

    cout<<"Functor:"<<endl;
    saxpi<float> f(kk1,kk2);
    v_out.clear();
    v_out.resize(v.size());
    thrust::transform(v.begin(),v.end(),v_out.begin(),f);


    for (size_t i = 0; i < v_out.size(); i++)
            std::cout << v_out[i] << std::endl;

}
```

Compile it using the following options: **--expt-extended-lambda  -std=c++11**

```
Lambda:
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
Functor:
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Can you explain the difference between __host__ __device__ and just __device__ ?

Comment: **__host__ __device__** is nothing but a shorthand for writing the function once and tell the compiler to produce two version of the same code: it produces x86 assembly for the CPU-side and PTX for the GPU.

Comment: This test example worked for me even without the `__host__` qualifier